# Facebook restricted our in-development app due to a Broken Google Play Store URL

Tags: facebook

So we have an in-development app that uses Facebook Login.

In Basic Settings we had to add the Android App Store platform so we can use the key hashes to test the app ourselves. We have also added the Package Name and Class.

The problem is Facebook has been repeatedly restricting our app because they try to access the Google Play Store URL and they flag it as broken. I told them each time our app is in Closed Beta so the link will indeed appear broken to those who are not invited but they just repeat the same thing all over again with no instructions on what we should do. Ocassionally they ask us when the app will be live.

I offered to add them to the Closed Beta Track and even gave them a link to an APK, but they just ignored it.

Has anyone encountered this. What should we do? We don't want to publish the app just for them.

I already tried:

- switching the app back to Development
- removing the Android platform from the Basic Settings (it leaves us unable to log in ourselves)
- giving them a link to an APK
- asking them to send us an email to add them to Closed Beta Track
- tried repling both with Yes and No to their question 'Is your app available to the general public?"